# Easiest way to test battery life?

Tags: battery

I'd like to test the battery life of my ubuntu 12.10 on my Think pad T520.  Are there any scripts or tools to log to a file? I'm seeing about 3 hours of use.

Answer (score 5):

In Power statistics you can view a graph with all the info you need.

```
Power Statistics > Laptop battery > History/Statistics
```

Comment: Power Statistics > Laptop battery > History/Statistics